TypeError: rt.toLowerCase is not a function nextjs
After creating a new next.js app with the latest 14.2.1, I get this error
 uncaughtException: TypeError: rt.toLowerCase is not a function
    at C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\next_projects\ecommerce\ecommerce-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:30:274042

I treid removing node_modules and reinstalling packages:
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

the same error still occurs

I was having the same problem (Nextjs "14.2.0") and I made a fresh start:

remove node_modules (all packages)
remove .next (build)
npm cache clean --force (clean the cache from npm)

After that, rebuild everything:

npm install (generate node_modules folder)
npm run dev (generate .next folder)

And it works. I hope it helps you

No working with npm run build. Needed to downgrade to NextJS v14.1.4

I was only able to resolve this by dropping back to version 14.1.4

I had to downgrade to Next 14.1.4, this error happened initially after I downloaded DaisyUI, then it happened every time I started a new create-next-app.

I had the same error, I'm using Next UI, I had to downgrade to Next 14.0.4

Seems to be related to the Console Ninja extension and has been fixed in its version 1.0.306, see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/64465#issuecomment-2058762833 for details.
